# Communication between different subsystem drivers(For ex: IIO and Charging driver)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, subsystem, iio

I wrote a driver for ADC module which is the part of IIO subsystem. It read voltages of various hardware peripherals connected to specific channel, and these voltages can be read only from sysfs.

My problem is that, my charging driver also want to read data from ADC, but there are no such API exposed so that Charging driver can communicate with the IIO subsystem driver(Driver-Driver communication).

My solution - Is it ok to write a function which will in itself calculate the ADC voltage of specific channel, send the voltage to charging driver. It fetches device details(driver_find_device), can call the handler function for read operation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A scheme that is extensible and portable is preferable to one that is not.  What you propose is not portable.  Use each driver to isolate its HW requirements. Have a userspace application to perform the interactions between the drivers.  Use a realtime priority if necessary.

Comment: Can charger work without ADC driver loaded? Does the hardware you are talking about is in SoC or it's totally separate stuff? 
P.S. Your proposal is not okay, though something similar might be done inside kernel.

Answer (score 3):

That is not true, there is a consumer API for in-kernel user. It is defined in [linux/iio/consumer.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/iio/consumer.h). Have a look at [drivers/hwmon/ii_hwmon.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/hwmon/iio_hwmon.c) or [drivers/power/axp288_fuel_gauge.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/power/axp288_fuel_gauge.c)for a usage exemple. You can also search for [iio_read_channel_raw](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=iio_read_channel_raw) but I would suggest using the processed version that will definitively more portable.

Comment: broken link to axp288_fuel_gauge.c. the file doesnt exist

Comment: It has been moved to http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/power/supply/axp288_fuel_gauge.c